# Error in python IOError:no such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7

When I try to run  module to open file in python with the following code:

```
from sys import argv

script,filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % (filename)
print txt.read()

print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input(">")

txt_again =open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

Gives me the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ex15_sample.txt'
```

Comment: Can you try raw_input and open part alone in Python console and check what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the file `ex15_sample.txt` is not in the current directory of execution ? Did you try to write the full path of the file at the `raw_input` step, ie `/tmp/ex15_sample.txt` ?